# WooCommerce: how to echo product variation?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am printing a stock/inventory report from WooCommerce.  How can I echo the products variations i.e. product color or size, etc?

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$product = new WC_Product_Variation( $loop->post->ID );
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></td>
<td><?php echo get_the_title( $loop->$product->get_attributes ); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product->sku; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product->stock; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
endwhile;
```

I have tried the following but I get something like: Variation #49379

```
<?php echo get_the_title( $loop->get_post_meta( $thepostid, '_product_attributes', true ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [woocommerce variations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466898/woocommerce-variations)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `echo $product->get_available_variations();`

If this is a single style template, make sure you add global $product; near the top.

Comment: I get an error.... Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Variation::get_available_variations()

Answer (score 0):

If you have product-id then this will be the solution

```
$product = wc_get_product($productid);
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

Now you may loop through this variation to print all variations.

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.