# How to add Variations tab in custom product type in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

- I've installed a plugin for "Gift Cards", which is basically adding a
  product type "Gift card".

  - I need to enhance its functionality.
  - There are other tabs available for this but the tab "Variations" is
    not.
  - How can i add this tab so my custom product type can also
    behave like a variable product.
  - Screen Shot: http://prntscr.com/ekogwd
  - And i've to use my custom product type strictly means i cannot change it to variable product type.
  - Is there any hook, action, or filter to add this tab manually to my custom product type "Gift card" using woocommerce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you've already added the Gift Card to the product type selector. However, I'm adding it here for completeness and because you ave to use the same name in the second function.

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'so_42835590_add_product_type' );
function so_42835590_add_product_type( $types ){

    // Key should be exactly the same as in the class product_type parameter
    $types[ 'gift-card' ] = __( 'Gift Card', 'your-plugin' );

    return $types;

}
```

You can add your own custom tabs by filtering `woocommerce_product_data_tabs` but you can also add classes to the existing tabs. Classes are what the metabox javascript uses to decide what to show and what to hide when the product type is changed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'so_42835590_product_data_tabs' );
function so_42835590_product_data_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $product_type = 'gift-card'; // must match array key in previous snippet

    // Add an additional class to an existing tab, ex: Variations.
    $tabs[ 'variations' ][ 'class' ][] = 'show_if_' . $product_type;  

    return $tabs;
}
```

**Edit** you do need to add some javascript to control the visibility of "Enabled for variations" tab in existing attributes, and when attributes are added. This should do the trick:

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {

    // Variable type options are valid for variable workshop.
    $( '.show_if_variable:not(.hide_if_gift-card)' ).addClass( 'show_if_gift-card' );

    // Trigger change
    $( 'select#product-type' ).change();

    // Show variable type options when new attribute is added.
    $( document.body ).on( 'woocommerce_added_attribute', function(e) {

        $( '#product_attributes .show_if_variable:not(.hide_if_gift-card)' ).addClass( 'show_if_gift-card' );

        var $attributes     = $( '#product_attributes' ).find( '.woocommerce_attribute' );

        if ( 'gift-card' == $( 'select#product-type' ).val() ) {
            $attributes.find( '.enable_variation' ).show();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking it works. Can you please add some more details, how to display checkbox field "Used for variations"  into attributes tab?  http://prntscr.com/el16t1 This only shows when product type is variable product.

Comment: See the script I've added.

Comment: Thankyou so much @helgatheviking

Comment: I followed the guide here, it seems to work fine, except that the Variations tab is now hidden when I select variable product type. What should I do?

Comment: @Ethan that should be handled by the 2nd snippet that filters `woocommerce_product_data_tabs`. I've tweaked it to make it a little more readable... the `gift-card` needs to be replaced with your product type and needs to match across all snippets.

Comment: @helgatheviking That's where the problem is for me, when my new 'show_if_abc' class is added, it makes the product tab hidden when I select any product types that are not abc.

Comment: @Ethan That's expected behavior though. If you create a custom tab specifically for a product type it should only show for that product type, no? You would take a different approach from what I've outlined in this answer if you aren't creating a custom product type and are instead creating a tab that is relevant for multiple product types.

Comment: I guess my explanation was not clear. So I have a new product type, do as you described to allow the "Variations" tab to show when the product type is my new type. But afterwards, on other variable products, the "Variations" tab is gone. I'm not talking about any new tabs.

Comment: @Ethan I'm not sure what to suggest as I can't reproduce that. I would double check that you are adding a new class to the the `$tabs['variations']['class']` array and _not_ replacing the existing values. As long as the original `show_if_variable` exists the tab should show for Variable products. You could try adding an `error_log(json_encode($tabs));` after https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L132 to take a look at the $tabs array after it's been filtered.

Comment: @helgatheviking, thanks for the snippet you shared. However, I am getting **This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.** for my product though I have entered the prices for all the variations. I also copied add to cart template of variable product and renamed it to giftcard.php and there i don't get the attributes of the giftcard product?