# Get Product variations based on product id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom template for product and I want to show the product variations on single product but not able to do it can anyone tell me how to get variations  here is my code

```
$productId = $_POST['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product( $productId );
    //print_r($product);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $productId ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    $product_data .='<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">';
    $product_data .='<img src="'.$image[0].'">';
    $product_data .= '<h4 class="title">'.$product->get_title().'</h4>';  
    $product_data .= '<p class="prodis">'.apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $productId) ).'</p>'; 
    $product_data .= '<p class="proprice">'.$product->get_price_html().'</p>';
    $product_data .= '<p class="addcardft">'.do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart').'</p>';
    $product_data .='</div></div>';              
    echo $product_data;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

more details here [woocommerce variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466898/woocommerce-variations)